# Ubunutu 20.04 LTS is freezing after reboot when second display is connected

Tags: updates, display, 20.04, restart

I have updated Ubuntu 20.04 LTS since last week. But every time when I restart the computer, it gets stuck like in the picture below.

[image: picture]

I found that when I remove the second display and do the restart, it works.
Does anyone else have the same problem?

Comment: btw, the physical restart after removing the hdmi is not working, unless you change the booting mode from Quick to Diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I did in 14.04, but never put in the time to solve it. That laptop also had issues with secondary displays after waking up from sleep.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in dell, but I had only one problem getting blurr screen background while I reboot the system.
This how it looks, PFA.[Blurr screen/sometimes totally dark screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAN5G.jpg)